# How perform cascade delete if colum doesn't have ON DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have colum1 from table1 without "ON DELETE CASCADE".

And colum2 from table2, colum3 from table3. Both have foreign key to colum1

How I can delete values from column1 and values from table 2 and table 3, that have foreign key to column1?

EDIT:
I can't delete rows from child tables then from parent table.
I have very huge database with complicated сonnections, where 
colum4 from table4 point to colum3 from table3 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ON DELETE CASCADE`, just `DELETE` rows from child tables then from parent table.

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE column2 = ?;

DELETE FROM table3
WHERE column3 = ?;

DELETE FROM table1
WHERE column1 = ?;
```

**EDIT:**

> I can't delete rows from child tables then from parent table. I have very huge database with complicated сonnections, where colum4 from table4 point to colum3 from table3 and so on.

It is always safer to do it explicitly than depending on multiple cascaded `DELETE` where you can end up with unintended deletions.

Comment: @macmoonshine It could be also very dangerous. I prefer explicit `DELETE` :)

Comment: Note that if you try to delete from parent, postgresql will TELL you which child rows fail. So you could try the delete on the parent, grab the error, parse it, and then delete the child table rows.

Answer (score 0):

You simply delete the child records before you delete the parent record.  Outside of the CASCADE, there is no other way to accomplish this.  Databases have DDL for a reason; right, wrong, or indifferent.